# Phalcon logger / fileAdapter not working

Tags: php, logging, phalcon

I am trying to make a logger working in PhalconPHP for debugging purposes.

But no matter what code I try to use, it gives me this error when loading the browser:

```
Can't open log file at 'app/logs/test.log'
#0 /home/myuser/public_html/demo1/app/controllers/UsersController.php(6): Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File->__construct('app/logs/test.l...')
#1 [internal function]: unknown()
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Loader->autoLoad('UsersController')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('UsersController')
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /home/myuser/public_html/demo1/public/index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#7 {main}

<?php

use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File as FileAdapter;

// Create the file logger in 'w' mode
$logger = new FileAdapter("app/logs/test.log", array(
    'mode' => 'w'
));
```

FYI: All the logger codes are tested in a Phalcon controller.

---

```
$logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File("app/logs/test.log");

$logger->log("This is a message");
$logger->log(\Phalcon\Logger::ERROR, "This is an error");
$logger->error("This is another error");

$logger->close();
```

---

```
use Phalcon\Logger;
use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File as FileAdapter;

$logger = new FileAdapter("app/logs/test.log");

$logger->log(
    "This is a message"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend not using relative path, but absolute.

In your case it seems like absolute path is:
/home/myuser/public_html/demo1/app/logs/test.log

Secondly check if the php user (commonly in web server it is www-data) has the rights to write to logs directory (for example make www-data own dir logs).

And last thing that I encounter sometimes is, when you use cli, the log file is owned by shell user, then www-data user cannot write to that file. Make either different logs for cli or just delete logs.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use APP_PATH

```
$logger = new FileAdapter(APP_PATH.'app/logs/test.log', ['mode' => 'w']);
```